zoho deluge automatic export of zoho survey into local spreadsheet
I would like to create deluge function which allows to automatically export zoho survey response to a spreadsheet on a local file.

I found some documentation on how to do this:
https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/automatic-csv-export-from-zoho-survey-response
The aim is to use the Schedule report: it sends a mail with a summary in XLS, CSV or PDF format.

To schedule a report:


Click Actions and select  Schedule Report.
Enter a name for your report in the Name box.
Select the frequency to email reports: Daily, Weekly, or Monthly.
Click the Select a report dropdown menu and choose the type of report you want to schedule.
Click All data to receive all responses.
Click Data acquired within frequency interval to receive responses for a specific time period.
Click Select a filter to set a filter for reports.
Click the drop-down arrow next to Language, to choose the language of the report, if you have multiple languages in your survey.
In the Recipient's email addresses box, enter the email addresses of the recipients, separated by commas.
Click Save.


Could you [edit] your answer to include the key points from the documentation? If the link goes stale, it's difficult for people with the same issue to read up on it otherwise.
